# How to get an attribute's anim curve between utility nodes?

Tags: python, maya

I'm very aware about `cmds.listHistory` and `cmds.listConnections`, but they fail miserably here.

Let's say I have a 3 objects:

`A` has a custom attribute that drives `C`'s visibility.

Between that connection let's say there's a bunch of utility nodes.

And finally there's `B` that drives one of the utility nodes but has nothing to do with `C`.

If I set keyframes on `A`'s custom attribute, how can find from `C` the anim curve that's driving it? If this was a direct connection it would be easier to solve, but it's not. If `B` is also animated it will fetch both anim curves. In fact if `A` has no anim curve but `B` does listing history will grab `B`'s anim curve, which is totally bogus!

This feels like it's impossible to get the anim curve that's driving `C`'s visibility without mistaking it with another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have something like this? Two nodes are connected to a utility node and the output of a utility node drives visibility of the node on the right side?

If so, I fear it is not possible to determine which input drives the visibility, you will have to do it yourself by iterating over all nodes.
[image: Something like this?]

Comment: Not exactly on the same node but similar idea where nodes are being recycled to have fewer of them. Yeah I was afraid of that, thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like visibility of `C` is a connected attribute, which doesn't really have keys as it is. Unless you setup some baking step to key it when `A` has a key?

Also maybe [driven keys](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Animation/files/GUID-2C048635-CDD2-4CF7-820D-A032204C8CE8-htm.html) helps?

Comment: eh no.. I'm looking to do a straight query, not make more of a mess :)